# Extract specific data from string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string

I have this string:

```
{'iconPath': '/img/theme/bungienet/icons/psnLogo.png', 'crossSaveOverride': 0, 'isPublic': False, 'membershipType': 3, 'membershipId': '4611686018467284386', 'displayName': 'Datto'}
```

from which i need to extract the data behind `'membershipId'`, i can't just cut it from character ... to character ..., because the length can be different. this is originally from the Destiny2 API and is part of this API Response:

```
{
    "ErrorCode": 1,
    "ErrorStatus": "Success",
    "Message": "Ok",
    "MessageData": {},
    "Response": [
        {
            "crossSaveOverride": 0,
            "displayName": "Datto",
            "iconPath": "/img/theme/bungienet/icons/psnLogo.png",
            "isPublic": false,
            "membershipId": "4611686018467284386",
            "membershipType": 3
        }
    ],
    "ThrottleSeconds": 0
}
```

The problem is just, that the `"Response":` tag, starts a list, where everything is just Index 0 alltogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
data =  {
    "ErrorCode": 1,
    "ErrorStatus": "Success",
    "Message": "Ok",
    "MessageData": {},
    "Response": [
        {
            "crossSaveOverride": 0,
            "displayName": "Datto",
            "iconPath": "/img/theme/bungienet/icons/psnLogo.png",
            "isPublic": false,
            "membershipId": "4611686018467284386",
            "membershipType": 3
        }
    ],
    "ThrottleSeconds": 0
}

membership_id = data["Response"][0]["membershipId"]
```